# RTRIM data past a certain character

Tags: sql, oracle, substring

I feel like the answer to this is simple, but I've been drawing blanks.  I've looked for similar questions/answers on here, but have came up with nothing, so here I am.

I'm needing to trim a column of data past a certain character, so that I can get the distinct beginning portions of the record, and the below isn't working:

```
select short_desc, rtrim(short_desc, ' :') from table_a 
select short_desc, rtrim(short_desc, ' : A1234567890') from table_a
```

current columns/data in `table_a`:

```
short_desc            part_no
MODULE F4 : A871006   abcde123
MODULE F4 : H871040   abcde123
MODULE F4 : H871044   abcde123
MODULE F4 : F871024   abcde123
MODULE F4 : H871038   abcde123
MODULE F4 : H871054   abcde123
MODULE F4 : H823107   abcde123
MODULE F4 : H815741   abcde123
```

What I'm needing to accomplish, is trimming all data from the `' :'` and to the right.  And my expected output, is trying to achieve distinct trimmed values from `table_a`.

Expected Result:
`'MODULE F4' 'abcde123'`

Comment: [rtrim](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/RTRIM.html) doesn't do what you think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`trim()` functions are to discard specific characters. In your case, you want to discard any text (regardless of characters) beyond a specific position. This is done with `substr()` and `instr()`, for example

```
substr(short_desc, 1, instr(short_desc, ' : ') - 1)
```

`instr` finds the position, in the string, of the first character in the substring to be matched (the first space in `' : '`). We subtract 1 because we don't want to include this space in the result.

Note that this will return `null` if the input string, `short_desc`, does not contain the `' : '` substring. If that is a problem, do say so; make sure to tell us what the required handling is in that case, as we can't guess your business requirement.

Comment: Thank you! Like I said, I knew the answer was simple, but for some reason my mind was stuck on the `trim` function.  I had tried `substr` as well with no success so just continued with `trim`.  I appreciate the explanation and extra note.  As far as I'm aware, the customer uses this `short_desc` format for all their parts in an excel spreadsheet for reporting, so `null` shouldn't be a factor.